# React Spring module not found

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

I want to use **react-spring** package in react project, but I am facing this error. But when I am using same code in **stackblitz** it is working without any problem. Could you please help me with this problem?

[image: module not found]

```
Version: 1.75.1 (user setup)
Commit: 441438abd1ac652551dbe4d408dfcec8a499b8bf
Date: 2023-02-08T21:32:34.589Z
Electron: 19.1.9
Chromium: 102.0.5005.194
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.23-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22621
Sandboxed: No
```

[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fyd4kg?file=src/App.js)

I am trying to use this animation library in my project though it is working in stackblitz not working in my pc.

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "toast-notification",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.13",
    "@react-spring/web": "^9.7.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "axios": "^1.2.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.6.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set port=3010 && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio": "^0.4.0",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.2",
    "@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "^0.4.0",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.2",
    "sass": "^1.57.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: did you run npm install?

Comment: yes I did, and this package is in my node modules folder

Answer (score 0):

First remove "@react-spring/web": "^9.7.0" from your package.json

1. Delete the node modules folder
2. Run `yarn add @react-spring/web`
3. Run `yarn`
4. Run `yarn run start`

Comment: I did this just now as you told me, same error again.

Answer (score 0):

okay from react-spring github discussion I got this feedback from **joshuaellis** [github discussion link](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-spring/issues/2097)

He suggested to use 9.6.1 for now till the fix the bug occurring for webpack update of ECMA script.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue in `9.7.0`, this has been solved in `9.7.1` try to upgrade to that version.